# Alexa Skill - Update Intent programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create an Alexa skill which has a fairly wide-open possible number of phrases it could use. Too many to write by hand.

I can probably generate the list programmatically, but it changes frequently, so I'd want it updated frequently.

Is there an Amazon API I can call to update the possible values for a custom slot type, without having to manually log in and copy and paste it all the time?

Comment: you could type it with your nose but your hands might be easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - Amazon does not provide an API for updating your skill.  I believe that API.AI provides this and they have an integration with Alexa ASK but I've heard that it's not very good and I don't really expect it to get better now that Google has bought them.

In your first paragraph it sounds like you are talking about supporting a lot of different utterances (ways of saying the same thing), but after that it sounds like you are talking about a large number of 'slot values': the relevant user input extracted from the utterances.  Either way, the answer is still no - no API.

I believe there are popular features requests for both a general API for updating the skills, and support for dynamic slot lists, [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/content/idea/45116/dynamic-or-per-user-value-list-for-custom-slots.html).

And [here's](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/why-a-custom-slot-is-the-literal-solution) Amazon's defence of the custom slot and how it can replace the (deprecated) literal slot.

Comment: Basically, I'm aiming for one (or a few) utterances with lots of possible values to fill in the blank. Previously, I would have used an literal and parsed it from there, but that'll soon no longer be an option.

Comment: @samanime ok, that's what I figured.  That is a common concern - lots of people were complaining about them removing the literal, so they publshed a blog post in response.  I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Some dynamic slot functionality is now available. See blog post this week: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/db4c0ed5-5a05-4037-a3a7-3fe5c29dcb65/use-dynamic-entities-to-create-personalized-voice-experiences . Note the current limitations toward the bottom of the post though.

Answer (score 6):

YES! See **Update Interaction Model** section at their docs.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-operations.html#update-interaction-model

Comment: is it also possible to add utterances in a way like this?

Comment: I believe so. It is called samples under intents section. https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-schema.html#sample-interaction-model-schema

Comment: Is this applicable to a released skill?

Comment: I think you cannot change skill already on LIVE. You need to submit it for approval.

Answer (score 1):

No, but there is now a beta editor which lets you drag a single JSON file containing all utterances, intents and slots. Log into the developer portal and click "Interaction Model Builder Beta".

Answer (score 0):

In case you're late to the party like I am, check out https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-intro.html for a full CLI/API which allows total model editing via JSON.