# How can I programmatically trigger an Alexa Skill intent?

Tags: iot, alexa-skills-kit

I have a few smart devices that can all be controlled through Alexa (e.g. "Hey Alexa, turn on the fan to 50% speed"). Is there an API that I can use to programmatically trigger certain Alexa Skill intent. I know there is a way to use [text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556358/alexa-skill-update-intent-programmatically) to do so, but that feels very janky, and I would love to know if there's a native API for Alexa intents that can be programmatically triggered.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible, It requires authentification and it is not available outside of Alexa, yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, Alexa does not expose an API.  The whole point of Alexa and the Echo devices is to provide a voice interface which then calls an API to get things done.  It seems like you want an API to trigger a voice response system that then calls an API to get something done.